# Is random_state=7 better inside a function than np.random.seed(7)?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, svm, random-seed

are both of the following functions completely reproducible?

```
def test_SVC_A():
    svc = LinearSVC(random_state=7)
    svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    svc.score(X_test, y_test)


def test_SVC_B():
    seed=7
    np.random.seed(seed)
    svc = LinearSVC()
    svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    svc.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Or should I prefer `test_SVC_A` to function `test_SVC_B`?

I find it confusing because I always get the same result in both procedures?

Comment: The first option allows `LinearSVC` to have its isolated random state. Currently they are the same but if you somehow need to produce other random numbers or use another library that produces random numbers then you will not get the same output with the same input because they will modify your random state.

Comment: ok thanks. Then it is probably better to use the first variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scikit-learn does not use its own global random state; whenever a
>   RandomState instance or an integer random seed is not provided as an
>   argument, it relies on the numpy global random state, which can be set
>   using numpy.random.seed

---

That being said, **adding** `np.random.seed()` **before** **importing** the `LinearSVC` **should lead to same results.**